# how to fetch data in while giving limit in slides

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

i am using a slideshow . i want to fetch the slides information from database . my slides structure is in first slide there is 3 records in second slide there is 3 records and the records are adding from back end so the records are increasing and all of those records i want to fetch in slides as segement of 3 records . how can i fetch like that records from database and put the while loop in php file the source which i used is below

```
<div class="flexslider">
<ul class="slides">
<?php 

$result = mysql_query('select * from facilities_home');
while($record = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
{
?>
<li>

<div class="test-one">

<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-1.png" alt="" class="mg" />
<p>Cable TV in each Room</p>
<h4>Dec-2010</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-3.png" alt="" class="mg" />
<p>30 kVA generator for power backup</p>
<h4>Feb-2011</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-2.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>Air conditioner in Double Occupancy Rooms</p>
<h4>Mar-2011</h4>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</li>
<?php
}
?>
<li>
<div class="test-one">
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-4.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>Refrigerator in each Room</p>
<h4>April-2013</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-5.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>Recreation Room at the resort, which is a "first in class" amenity.It has got 2 Carrom Boards, Table Tennis, Mini Pool Table, Chess, Magnetic Dart Board etc. </p>
<h4>Aug-2013</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-6.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>24 x 7 Hot water in Double Occupancy Rooms</p>
<h4>April-2016</h4>
</div>
<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</li>
<li>
<div class="test-one">
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-7.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>Intercom facility in Double Occupancy Rooms</p>
<h4>April-2016</h4>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 test-left">
<img src="images/test-8.png" alt="" class="mg"/>
<p>2 Sea facing Cottages developed</p>
<h4>Nov-2016</h4>
</div>

<div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

[image: there is a slider in which is want to fetch a result]

there is a slider in which is want to fetch a result please help me .

Answer (score 0):

Is it supposed to be `while` loop, because simply you can do this:

```
<?php 
    $result = mysql_query('select * from facilities_home');
    $records = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $newRecords = array_chunk(records, 3);

    foreach($newRecords as $treeRecords){
        foreach($treeRecords as $record){?>
            <div class="col-md-4 test-left">
                <img src="images/test-1.png" alt="" class="mg" />
                <p><?= $record['content']?></p>
                <h4><?= $record['date']?></h4>
            </div>
<?php 
        }
    }
?>
```

Read more about `array_chuncks()` from [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

Comment: not working sir   .   $records = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);  this will returns  only one records from database

Comment: It's a typo from copy pasting your code, simply fetch all your data from database as array and play with it using `array_chunk()`

Comment: sure sir already i did it but till $records = mysql_fetch_array($result); showing only one result .i am also confused how it will happen like that .